# NetLogo : How to set condition if 3 of neighbors4

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to write an if statement that executes a command if three of neighbors4 are the same color - right now, I am using all? but I want to broaden to 3 instead of 4 neighbors.

The code I tried does not give a boolean for the if statement

```
ask patches with [pcolor = black][
if n-of 3 neighbors4 [pcolor != black]
[set pcolor 55]
]
```

I also attempted to add in an = true? but that also resulted in an error

Comment: I ended up trying this :

    Ask patches with [pcolor = black]
    [if count neighbors4 with [pcolor = 55] = 3
    [set pcolor 55]  
    ]

which works, but I don't know if there's a better way

Comment: never say "resulted in an error"; always give the complete, exact text of the error message you got. that makes it much easier for someone to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly 3 or at least 3? If exactly 3, change the `<=` below to `=`.

There might be a simpler way, but here's what I came up:

```
let colors remove-duplicates [ pcolor ] of neighbors4
let three-share-color? not empty? filter [ 3 <= count neighbors4 with [ pcolor = ? ] ] colors
```

`remove-duplicates [ pcolor ] of neighbors4` gets the colors of the neighbors as a list, removing duplicates (though that's not strictly necessary). `filter [ 3 <= count neighbors4 with [ pcolor = ? ] ] colors` goes through each color, grabbing the neighbors that are that color, and checks to see if there are at least 3 of them. If there 3, it keeps the color, otherwise it tosses it. The `not empty?` checks to see if we have any colors left.

You can generalize this to any number, attribute, and agentset as follows:

```
to-report at-least-n-share [ n reporter agentset ]
  let attributes remove-duplicates [ runresult reporter ] of agentset
  report not empty? filter [ n <= count agentset with [ runresult reporter = ? ] ] attributes
end
```

For this problem, you would then call it like:

```
at-least-n-share 3 (task [ pcolor ]) neighbors4
```

Edit: Just to be clear, this is a generalized solution of "an if statement that executes a command if three of neighbors4 are the same color". I ignored the particular colors. However, if you know WHICH color the three should be ahead of time, then you just want:

```
if count neighbors4 with [ pcolor = the-color ] >= 3 [
  do-stuff
]
```

Again, make that `>=` and `=` if you meant exactly three.